# Can't get rid of hex characters

Tags: python

This program makes an array of verbs which come from a text file.

```
file = open("Verbs.txt", "r")
data = str(file.read())
table = eval(data)
num_table = len(table)
new_table = []
for x in range(0, num_table):
   newstr = table[x].replace(")", "")
   split = newstr.rsplit("(")
   numx = len(split)
   for y in range(0, numx):
       split[y] = split[y].split(",", 1)[0]
       new_table.append(split[y])
   num_new_table = len(new_table)
for z in range(0, num_new_table):
    print(new_table[z])
```

However the text itself contains hex characters such as in

```
('a\\xc4\\x9fr\\xc4\\xb1[Verb]+[Pos]+[Imp]+[A2sg]', ':', 17.6044921875)('A\\xc4\\x9fr\\xc4\\xb1[Noun]+[Prop]+[A3sg]+[Pnon]+[Nom]', ':', 11.5615234375)
```

I'm trying to get rid of those. How am supposed to do that?

I've looked up pretty much everywhere and decode() returns an error (even after importing codecs).

Comment: Can you include a sample of the contents of "verbs.txt"?

Comment: Looks like you have `aÄŸrÄ±` as your verb if you decode it as unicode. Since this is most likely trash, you need to know what encoding was used to write the file in the first place before you can do anything with it.

Comment: Also, show how you use decode and what error it gives.

Comment: `data = str(file.read())` is useless at best - `file.read()` returns a `str` already - calling`eval()` on untrusted data is a _huge_ security issue and certainly not the right way to parse your data, and you can iterate directly over a sequence, no need for the "x in range(len(whatever))". Perhaps you should start with getting rid of all this nonsense ?

Comment: How am I supposed to parse my data?

Comment: Are you parsing Turkish (or a similar language) text? `C49F` is a valid UTF8 encoding for [g breve "ğ"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/11f/index.htm). If this is the case, you should not try to "get rid" of these characters. The word in your example reads "ağrı" which indeed is a [verb](http://www.wordreference.com/tren/ağrı).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [parse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse), a python module that allows you to search inside a string for regularly-formatted components, and, from the components returned, you could extract the corresponding integers, replacing them from the original string.

For example (untested alert!):

```
import parse

# Parse all hex-like items
list_of_findings = parse.findall("\\x{:w}", your_string)

# For each item
for hex_item in list_of_findings:

    # Replace the item in the string
    your_string = your_string.replace(
        # Retrieve the value from the Parse Data Format
        hex_item[0],
        # Convert the value parsed to a normal hex string,
        # then to int, then to string again
        str(int("0x"+hex_item[0]))
    )
```

Obs: instead of "int", you could convert the found hex-like values to characters, using `chr`, as in:

```
chr(hex_item[0])
```

Comment: ImportError: No module named 'parse'

Comment: "parse" is not a part of the Python default library. You can install it with "pip install parse"